Is the Advanced Editor the only way to copy a query out of Power BI?
I am relatively new to Power BI. I have inherited 85 or so reports spread out across dozens of workspaces. I need to modify the queries used to pull data into some of the reports. The only approach I have been able to find is to to use the Advanced Editor. Unfortunately the Query is full of "#(tab)" and "#(lf)" and I have to use find and replace to clean it up before I can use it in SQL Management Studio. This is completely absurd. There must be some other way.

